# In Luke 1:76, does the term "Most High" refer to Jesus?

Tags: jesus

John 3:31 New International Version

> The one who comes from above is above all; the one who is from the earth belongs to the earth, and speaks as one from the earth. The one who comes from heaven is above all.

Luke 1:76 New International Version

> And you, my child, will be called a prophet of the Most High; for you will go on before the Lord to prepare the way for him,

In Luke 1:76, does the term "Most High" refer to Jesus?

Answer (score 2):

It refers to "God Most High," a title for God first mentioned in the story of  Abraham's feast with and Melchizedek.

Genesis 14:18

> And Melchizedek the king of Salem brought out bread and wine; now he
> was a priest of God Most High.

In Hebrew this is "el elyon." The epithet "elyon" (most high) is used numerous times in the Hebrew Bible. Jesus is called "son of the Most High God" in Mark 5:7 and several times in the Gospel of Luke.

Comment: Correct. The "Most High" is Almighty God YHWH Himself.

Comment: There are some objections: 1) The word most high is not accompanied by the word God. 2) As you explained, it is equivalent to the word עֶלְיוֹן֙ H05945 in Psalm 89:27: "Also I will make him my firstborn, higher than the kings of the earth."

Comment: One question that arises is whether Luke 1:76 is the fulfillment of the prophecy cited in Psalm 89:27.